# Set the background colour of the view when the UIView is shifted down

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I need to bring down my UIView down by 50 points.
When I do that the top position background turns black since it does not have any view in that portion.

[image: Screenshot of how it looks]

**I want the black area to be filled with white colour.**

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:stubController animated:YES];
    CGRect newFrame = self.navigationController.view.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = 50;
    self.navigationController.view.frame= newFrame;
```

Could some one help me to set the background to white.

Answer (score 1):

try set windows background color in `AppDelegate` like this:

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: You mean `self.window.backgroundColor` not `windows`.

Comment: where should i place this?. In which method?.